# SSL connection self-signed certificate with p12 key Android Apache

Tags: java, android, ssl

I have faced with the problem making ssl connection between android and apache server. I have self-signed certificate in PKCS12. I try do following:

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
                keyStore.load(certificateStream, password);

```
            TrustManagerFactory tmf1 = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf1.init(keyStore);

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(keyStore, password);

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");


            sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf1.getTrustManagers(), null);


            // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
            URL url =new URL("https://172.20.175.1/kani/");
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

And on last line:

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

I get following exception:

```
04-11 11:35:30.123: W/System.err(4880): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
04-11 11:35:30.133: W/System.err(4880):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:401)
04-11 11:35:30.133: W/System.err(4880):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
04-11 11:35:30.133: W/System.err(4880):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
04-11 11:35:30.133: W/System.err(4880):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
etc...
```

Problem is what sslContext variable was not initialized by my p12 key. I watched in debug mode this variable and did not find any trace of my p12 key. Please help, i have tryed many solutions and nothing has come.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#HttpsExample

Comment: Android was unable to verify its authenticity, so "trust anchor not found" check the server that it is connecting to correct and returning the intermediate certificate correct

Comment: Could you tell me how can i check it?

Comment: i have a few certificates was issued me by server: .crt, .jks, .bks, .p12, i don't know which i must use. I did the same on ubuntu and it was easier then for android, then i use p12 cert and everythind was ok.

Comment: http://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html

Comment: I dont know what is wrong.I do same under ubuntu:

FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream("lamkin.p12");
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
 keystore.load(fIn, password);
 SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(keystore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
 SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1" }, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
 CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

And its work properly